# Аналоги функций Python str и int в С++

Tags: c++, python

В Python есть две функции: **str** и **int**.
Есть ли возможность так переключаться между строкой и числом в C++?
У меня есть `a = 10`. Можно ли это число перевести в строку (после всех вычислений)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Функция `std::to_string` переводит число в строковое представление (в `std::string`). Для перевода числа в представление C-строки используется функция `std::sprintf`.

Функция `std::stoi` (`std::stol`, `std::stoll` и т.п.), а также функция `std::from_chars` переводят строку в число.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 10;
char s[3];
itoa(a, s, 10);
```

Comment: Ни в стандартной библиотеке C++, ни в стандартной библиотеке С не существует функции `itoa`.

Comment: @AnT, как так? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

Comment: @Александр, itoa - это нестандартная функция и компилятор не обязан её поддерживать, о чём кстати, написано в статье по вашей ссылке в разделе **Portability**

Comment: @Александр: Ваша ссылка никак не означает, что эта функция имеет какое-то отношение к языкам С или С++.

Comment: @Embedder ага, не знал. Но тем mingw и vc++ её поддерживают, как родную. Мне хватает :)